# Weird error while deploying app to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-ee

I'm getting error

```
Failed to initialize App Engine SDK at /home/xxx/workspace/myApp/war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.5.2.jar
Unable to find /home/xxx/workspace/myApp/war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.5.2.jar/lib/shared
```

While deploying app to App Engine from eclipse.

I have the jar appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.5.2.jar in classpath.

EDIT :: This project was initially j2ee application

Answer (score 0):

Though it will difficult to reproduce your problem without ur code but here is something that u might want to have a look. Refer  [Initialization Failed](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/java.html#initfailed)